# Loading resources in a plug-in works in eclipse but not for maven

Tags: resources, rcp, platform, e4

I am trying to load resources with the platform `URL` [approach](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fplatform-scheme-uri.html) in an `e4` `RCP` application.
This works fine for my application plug-in. But I have got a second plug-in which extends the application via `fragments`. In this plug-in this approach

```
platform:/plugin/<name>/<path>
```

does not work. If I start the project from eclipse though, the resources can be loaded.
What could I be doing wrong?

The build.properties content of the plug-in is as follows:

```
source.. = src
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
           .,\
           plugin.xml,\
           fragment.e4xmi,\
           res/
```

Comment: Are you sure everything in your plugin is listed in the build.properties?

Comment: @greg-449 Pretty sure, the file is located in the folder "res". I added the build.properties content to the original post.

Comment: Please post the code snippet you're using to get the file uri

Comment: @Arcadien Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:
The Maven build is case sensitive for file names, while eclipse is not.

```
new URL("platform:/plugin/name/res/myfile.txt")
new URL("platform:/plugin/name/res/myFile.txt")
```

In eclipse, both versions are working; from maven build, only the second version.
This seems quite strange to me. It would be great if anyone could explain this.

Comment: it seems to be no diff between two lines?

Comment: Fragments does not have its own classloader, afaik

Comment: @Arcadien the difference: ..file.txt <-> ..File.txt. That's why it was kind of tricky to find this problem :). But how does the classloader come into place here?